# Less than character as a search condition in T-SQL rather than operator syntax

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Now I'm writing a sql to select from a column that contains a '<' character. But the sql

`select * from data a where contains(a.name,'<')`

could not get any result. But

`select * from data a where a.name like '%<%'`

could.

I want to use contains method to accomplish this, is there any suggestion about this? I am using SQL Server 2019.

Here's my table:

```html
<table>
<tr><td>id</td><td>name</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>FTSE STRIPS <1 Yr USD</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>FTSE STRIPS 10+ Yr USD</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>FTSE STRIPS 10-15 Yr USD</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `CONTAINS`  is used for searching for words. `<` isn't a word it's a special character and it very likely treated as a stop character/word. `CONTAINS` and `LIKE` or not equivilents; that operator very differently.

Comment: You can use CHARINDEX if wants to ignore LIKE.

Comment: Upvote from me due to how this table is created - well done

Answer (score 1):

You can use CHARINDEX if wants to avoid LIKE.

```
SELECT * 
FROM data a 
WHERE CHARINDEX('<',a.name,0) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why you can't use the LIKE-operator? From your example it does appear to be applicable.

According to the [CONTAINS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) it only works "full-text indexed columns containing character-based data types". Maybe that is your issue?

Comment: We are not allowed to use LIKE-operator for performance issue, therefore I'm looking for another solution.